# Spring Bootを2.3.0にバージョンアップしたら、 Unresolved reference: validation が出る

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-boot

`Spring Boot`を`2.3.0`にバージョンアップしたら

```
import javax.validation.Valid
```

としていた箇所で、`Unresolved reference: validation` が出ました。
他にも、似たような箇所で、 `Unresolved reference: NotBlank` や`Unresolved reference: Size` 等が出ました。
どうすればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [javax.validation.constraints missing in 2.3.0? · Issue #21465 · spring-projects/spring-boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21465)
- [Spring Boot 2.3 Release Notes · spring-projects/spring-boot Wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters)

上記のリンクにある通り、`spring-boot-starter-validation` への依存関係を自分で示す必要があります。

私の場合は、`build.gradle.kts`を使っているので、 `build.gradle.kts` に下記を追加で動きました。

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
```